# Why does this form re-renders all the form players?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm using Svelte (and Kit) to create a new project for the first time finally!

I reproduced it here: https://stackblitz.com/github/frederikhors/svelte-form-re-renderings.

([Github project here](https://github.com/frederikhors/svelte-form-re-renderings))

As you can see in the below gif when I edit one of the player in the form all the other players re-render too.

**Why?**

[image: iss]

I expect only the player I'm editing to re-render due to the updated data in it.

If I add 6 players for example it re-renders all the 6 players!

Am I wrong?

#### Another smaller REPL

https://svelte.dev/repl/04b128896e584554b399be0b33f0d5a7?version=3.59.1

#### Relevant code

- App.svelte:

```html
<script>
    import FormPlayer from './FormPlayer.svelte';
    
    let form = {};
    
    if (!form.players?.length) AddPlayer();
    
    function AddPlayer() {
        form.players = [...(form.players || []), {id: Date.now().toString()}];
    }
    
    function DeletePlayer(e) {
        const deletedId = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-id');
        if (!deletedId) return;
        form.players = form.players?.filter((p) => p.id !== deletedId);
    }

    $: average_age = (form.players?.reduce((sum, r) => sum + (r.age || 0), 0) ?? 0) / (form.players?.length || 0);
    
    function submit() {
        console.log("form:", form);
    }
</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={() => submit(form)}>
    <div>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Team name</label>

            <input type="name" id="name" bind:value={form.name} />
        </div>

        <!-- <div>
            <SelectCoach required bind:id={form.coachId} />
        </div> -->
    </div>

    <br />

    <div>
        <ul>
            {#each form.players || [] as player (player.id)}
                <FormPlayer bind:player {DeletePlayer} />
                <br />
            {:else}
                <h3>Still no player</h3>
            {/each}
        </ul>
    </div>

    <button type="button" on:click={AddPlayer}>Add new player</button>

    <br /><br />

    <div>
        Average age of players: {average_age}
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

- FormPlayer.svelte:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    export let DeletePlayer;
    export let player;

    $: console.log('Inside FormPlayer.svelte:', player);
</script>

<li>
    <div>
        <label for="name">Player Name</label>

        <input type="text" bind:value={player.name} />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="age">Age</label>

        <input type="number" bind:value={player.age} />
    </div>

    <button on:click={DeletePlayer} data-id={player.id}>Remove player</button>
</li>
```

Comment: Include all relevant code *in* the question, if it is a lot, reduce it first.

Comment: @H.B. Thanks, but maybe I should open another question to understand what is the "relevant" code for this issue in the first place! LOL

Comment: Code is relevant if it contributes to the issue, if it can be deleted and the issue is still there it was not relevant. "reduce" does not mean "omit", it means delete and rewrite. Delete all variables, components and elements that are not necessary. It should be possible to copy the code run it and see the issue. The code you have posted is *not* that, it references variables and components whose code/values are not shown.

Comment: @H.B. thanks. I don't know how to recreate this in one file only, but I did in two, see the small REPL.

Comment: It's fine to add multiple pieces of code as long as everything unnecessary is removed.

Comment: @H.B. done! Can you help me understand?

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with Svelte, but I'm pretty sure that what's being demonstrated here isn't "rerendering" since Svelte updates only in places where a variable that it depends on changes. What's happening here is a reactive script that runs whenever `player` updates, even if it's not tied to a UI update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Samathingamajig noted is pretty much correct. Svelte works via invalidation, the `bind:player` in the `#each` causes `form` to be invalidated when a player is edited in the component (because `players` comes from `form`).

`form` being invalidated then propagates back down through all items in the `#each` loop thus triggering the reactive statement in the component. The reactive statement being triggered is not necessarily an indication that anything will "render".

In this case nothing happens because Svelte checks whether the values changed before doing anything:

```js
// compiled output
if (dirty & /*player*/ 1 && input0.value !== /*player*/ ctx[0].name) {
    set_input_value(input0, /*player*/ ctx[0].name);
}

if (dirty & /*player*/ 1 && to_number(input1.value) !== /*player*/ ctx[0].age) {
    set_input_value(input1, /*player*/ ctx[0].age);
}
```